# Unprintable characters as input in command line

Tags: command-line, input, standard

I've got a program that requires some unprintable characters like *0x0F* (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) as input to execute the intended part of the program.

```
0       000     00              NUL     &#000;          Null char 
1       001     01              SOH     &#001;          Start of Heading
2       002     02              STX     &#002;          Start of Text
3       003     03              ETX     &#003;          End of Text
4       004     04              EOT     &#004;          End of
```

And it is being executed on command line, any idea how to insert unprintable chars to command line as input of a program?

Comment: The listing of ASCII control characters doesn't really belong in this question. The precise input required by the program (command-line parameters? Standard input? Something else?) would be a useful addition, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this command did the job

```
printf '\x0f\x11' | program
```

Answer (score 7):

The `printf` utility supports octal character escapes:

> 3. In addition to the escape sequences shown in XBD File Format Notation ( `'\\'`, `'\a'`, `'\b'`, `'\f'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'`, `'\v'` ), `"\ddd"`, where *ddd* is a one, two, or three-digit octal number, shall be written as a byte with the numeric value specified by the octal number.

The builtin `printf` in at least Bash and Zsh also supports hexadecimal escape sequences `\xHH` and also the `$'...'` quotes, that interpolate the escape sequences similarly.

So to use such characters in command line arguments to some command, do something like this:

```
$ somecmd "arg_with_$(printf '\017')_xoff"
```

or put it in a variable if you need to use the character more than once

```
$ xoff=$(printf '\017')
$ somecmd "many${xoff}odd${xoff}chars"
```

---

Or, to pipe the two bytes `0x0f 0x11` (`017 021` in octal) to a command as mentioned in the comments:

```
$ printf "\x0f\x11" | somecmd...
$ printf "\017\021" | somecmd...
```

Comment: how can I use your suggestion to covert  0x0f 0x11 to values that can be given as input to the program in shell?

Comment: @F.sb, well, those are hexadecimal numbers, so `\x0f' and '\x11' or use a calculator to change them to octal.

Comment: Concretely, `printf '\x0f\x11' | program` to pass these two bytes as standard input to `program`

Comment: @tripleee yup that'a right

Comment: @tripleee  write your solution as answer not comment, to be accepted as answer

Comment: I only clarified what was already implied here, and with the latest edit, it's explicitly in this answer now. You shoud aocept this answer.

Comment: Your `xoff=$(printf '\017')` can be done as `xoff=$'\017'`

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the shell; ZSH offers a `$\NNN` form

```
% perl -e 'printf "%vx\n", shift' $'\177'
7f
%
```

In both `zsh` and `ksh` another option would be to use <kbd>control+v</kbd> and then <kbd>return</kbd> which should insert a `^M` onto the command line, though this can be tedious and may overly complicate the shell history.

Lacking these, another option is to run a program that emits the appropriate characters

```
% perl -e 'printf "%vx\n", shift' $( perl -e 'print "\x0F"' )
f
%
```

Or to use a small C program with the appropriate arguments for your program; this will avoid any complications the shell might add

```
#include <err.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    execlp("perl", "perl", "-e", "printf \"%vx\\n\", shift", "\x0F",
           (char *) 0);
    err(1, "exec failed");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: hmm, ok then how can I insert ascii of 0x11 for example as input of a program in linux shell?

Comment: Depends on the shell, but the `zsh` notation mentioned in this answer is available in Bash (the default shell on many distros) as well; `$'\x11'`

Comment: @triplee, `$'...'` actually comes from ksh93 (while the `$'\uXXXX'` variant comes from `zsh`). It's now also available in `zsh`, `bash`, FreeBSD `sh` and `mksh` (and will probably be in the next major version of the POSIX standard).